# Creating a file Uri in C#

Tags: c#, .net, uri

I think I'm missing something obvious....

I've been reading code in a new project and have encountered code equivalent to the following:

```
var filePath = @"C:\temp\tmp1234.tmp";    // Generally obtained from System.IO.* calls
var uri = new Uri("file://" + filePath);
```

I thought that would be equivalent to:

```
var filePath = @"C:\temp\tmp1234.tmp";
var uri = new Uri(filePath);
```

(assuming the Uri class can parse the file path, deduce the scheme and do whatever escaping needs doing).

Since the code seems to work and this being done so frequently and so consistently I'm assuming the original developer had a good reason for using the `"file://" + filePath` idiom.  Could someone clue me in about what that reason might be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both generate completely identical `Uri` objects, except (obviously) for the `OriginalString`.

You can see this in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net):

```
var filePath = @"C:\temp\tmp1234.tmp";    // Generally obtained from System.IO.* calls
new []{ 
    new Uri("file://" + filePath),
    new Uri(filePath)
}.Dump();
```

I would guess that the original developer wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Nifty tool.  Playing around with it I see that there is a difference if filePath = @"C:\temp\temp12%34.tmp"!  using "file://" seems to assume it's already been URL-encoded so the LocalPath comes out munged (or at least not what was put in: C:\temp\temp124.tmp).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, adding "file://" forces the scheme, and therefore skips the need for .NET to call the "ParseSchemeCheckImplicitFile" method... so... it's [negligibly] faster.

That, and, it's explicit - which I prefer personally.

EDIT: Actually, what I should have said is it skips a lot of code in that method.